# code work on 1 out of 2 androids

Tags: android, crash

I am trying to make an app for android. I am using the app aide. I use the nvidia shield tablet with this code:

```
gl.glLineWidth(1f);     gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);     gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        float[] T1 = new float[]{0, 0, 1, -1};
        ByteBuffer T2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(T1.length * 4);
        T2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer T3 = T2.asFloatBuffer();
        T3.put(T1);
        T3.position(0);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, T3);
        byte[] T4 = new byte[]{(byte)255, 105, (byte)180, (byte)255, 105, (byte)180};
        ByteBuffer T5 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(T4.length);
        T5.put(T4);
        T5.position(0);
        gl.glColorPointer(3, Vulkan.gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, T5);
        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_LINES, 0, 2);
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

and it works but on the samsung galaxy s4 the app crash.

drawing texture works on both. 
can anyone help please

Comment: what/where crashes? show us the logs!

Comment: it crash at gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_LINES, 0, 2);